# Setting Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties in a Spring framework application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection, owasp

I am adding OWASP.CsrfGuard.jar to my spring 3.2.4 application to prevent CSRF attacks, but I am not sure how to config it.
The entry point of my application is

http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/welcome.do

From this controller ( WelcomeController ) depending of some conditions the view could be different:

```
....

    if (usr.getValidated().booleanValue() == Boolean.FALSE) {
                    return new ModelAndView("createAccountRedirectView");
                } else {
                    if (usr.getUserRole().equals(UserRole.MARKETING_SALES_TEAM_MEMBER)) {
                        return new ModelAndView("listAccountsRedirectView");                                    
                    } else if (usr.getUserRole().equals(UserRole.MANAGER)) {
                        return new ModelAndView("redirectingManageView");
                    } else {
                        return new ModelAndView(getView());
                    }
                }
    ....
```

Here my Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties :

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ConsoleLogger
org.owasp.csrfguard.NewTokenLandingPage=/devices/welcome.do
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=true
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPagePrecreate=false

org.owasp.csrfguard.Ajax=true

org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log=org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log
org.owasp.csrfguard.action.Log.Message=potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:%user%, ip:%remote_ip%, uri:%request_uri%, error:%exception_message%)

org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Public=/devices/welcome.do

org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=OWASP_CSRFTOKEN
org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=OWASP_CSRFTOKEN
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenLength=128
org.owasp.csrfguard.PRNG=SHA1PRNG
```

and here the result in the console:

```
[Thu Oct 08 10:17:26 CEST 2015] [Info] CsrfGuard analyzing request /devices/welcome/welcome.do
[Thu Oct 08 10:17:26 CEST 2015] [Info] CsrfGuard analyzing request /devices/welcome.do
[Thu Oct 08 10:17:26 CEST 2015] [Error] potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:joanet, ip:12
7.0.0.1, uri:/devices/welcome.do, error:required token is missing from the request)
<08-Oct-2015 10:17:31 o'clock CEST> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 127.
0.0.1:54,138 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
```